# Power BI Merge and Character Set Problem - Data

Tags: merge, powerbi

A field that causes the Power BI Merge and left anti join to not work ?

In Sharepoint it is this shown like this - ELEKTRÄ°K SÄ°STEMLERÄ° LTD.ÅžT
In Azure Data Bricks it is shown like this - ELEKTRİK SİSTEMLERİ LTD.ŞT  ( LOOKS DIFFERENT ?  THE “RİK” bit )

We got a key that uses this Manafacturer Name. This is used to do a Comparison between the SharePoint list and the Azure Data Bricks Table and work out the deleted records .

In Power BI there is a couple of records where the Merge and the left ant join don’t work . These are the keys of the records that do not work . So this is how this key is seen in the backend of Power BI ( Power Query side )

```
ELEKTRÄ°K SÄ°STEMLERÄ° LTD.ÅžT ( FROM SHAREPOINT LIST DATA SOURCE IN POWER BI ) 

ELEKTRÄ°K SÄ°STEMLERÄ° LTD.ÅžT ( FROM AZURE DATA BRICKS DATA SOURCE IN POWER BI )
```

Looks the same so should match and not be returned as a deleted record .

In Power BI Merge statement do not work with this key for some reason ? Is it a special Character set problem ? Any way round it ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to verify locale settings for your source.
You can also change columnTypes using a specific locale.

[image]

[image]